# Do LinkedIn has any web hook that provide live updates on every mentions and comments on a LinkedIn page

Tags: node.js, callback, linkedin-api, webhooks

I want the live notifications from LinkedIn when ever a person mentions or comments on my page.
Is there any web hook to get these details?
While searching on google I found that there is an API 'Marketing Developer Platform'.But I this product is not present in the products list in the LinkedIn developer page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Admins of organization pages can get webhook notifications through [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-social-action-notifications?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http). More details on the Marketing Developer Platform and how to get access are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/?view=li-lms-2023-02).